# URL encoding in R - giving different result?

Tags: r, url, encoding

I'm doing web scraping in South Korean newspaper websites, but I'm having trouble dealing with url encoding. The original keyword was "실업률"(unemployment rate), and first I tried using [URLencode] and [curlEscape] functions(i.e. url_key <- URLencode("실업률")). Both gave me same result,

"%BD%C7%BE%F7%B7%FC"

But this did not work properly during scraping. On the other hand, using URL encoding site (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), I got

"%EC%8B%A4%EC%97%85%EB%A5%A0"

and it worked well.

But still, I don't know what caused different output and how to get the latter output in R. Thanks for responds in advance.

(Responding to comments, I added my result of sessionInfo() below)

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.8 bitops_1.0-6   plyr_1.8.4     stringr_1.1.0 
[5] XML_3.98-1.4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.4   Rcpp_0.12.7   stringi_1.1.2
```

Comment: I don't know anything about scraping in Korean, but have you looked at `rvest` package?

Comment: Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`? When I do `URLencode("실업률")` on my macOS system, it comes back as "`%EC%8B%A4%EC%97%85%EB%A5%A0`"

Comment: @AmitKohli Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you. I added it.

Comment: Not sure this will work (I can't set my locale to yours), but try: `withr::with_locale(c(LC_CTYPE="C", LC_COLLATE="C"), URLencode("실업률"))` (you'll need to install the `withr` package)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for careful instruction! Actually it gave me the same result but I'm feel really indebted you spend your time for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking 실 (U+C2E4), we see that it's UTF-8 value is `0xEC 0x8B 0xA4` (3 bytes). That matches the expected URL-encoding. It appears that your incorrect result is caused by another character set (EUC-KR?)

Comment: Your hint solved my problem! I discovered that my default encoding is "cp949", and two lines, 
ff <- iconv("실업률", from="CP949", to="UTF-8")
gg <- URLencode(ff)
yielded the desired result! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows defaults to CP949 for Korean.

But there is confusion as to whether EUC-KR is equivalent to CP949 or not.

The whatwg specs list EUC-KR as a standard, but their definition of EUC-KR is identical to Windows CP949. They list "CP949" as a deprecated name. Also, the EUC-KR used in Linux is this.

But, Windows/IBM/Python/Iconv/(likely others) have CP949 and EUC-KR as different. In these, CP949 is a superset of the older EUC-KR, able to encode more hangul blocks.

So, you can get a situation where you think something is EUC-KR, but your system's EUC-KR isn't compatible with it. I've had this issue, where an encoding guessing library tells you a file is EUC-KR, but then when I convert it from EUC-KR -> UTF-8, everything fails because the system would only work with it being CP949.